# QTabWidget with multiple line?

Tags: qt4, qtabwidget

Is it possible to make QTabWidget behave like windows system , use multiple line when there's just too much tabs ?

I checked qt's doc , seems no such thing was available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to subclass `QTabWidget` or `Widget` and implement this functionality yourself. I would recommend that you consider a different approach if you plan more tabs than will conveniently all fit in a single line (without arrows or multiple rows). Tabs on multiple rows, although common enough, are widely considered to be a bad UI experience. A single row with arrows is only marginally better :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement QTabBar to render the lines differently, and then use QTabWidget::setTabBar() to your new implementation.