# How to make a second line in QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt

How to make a second line in TAB ? (like \n )

Like:

```
tab->setTabText(index, QString::fromStdString("U: \n S:" ));
tab->setTabText(index, QString::fromStdString("U: <br> S:"));
```

Comment: Dow you mean `QTabWidget`?

Comment: it is not available at the moment, you can inherit qt classes an implement it by yourself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542115/qtabwidget-with-multiple-line